# Outlook synchronization and ai.exe

Tags: microsoft-outlook, gmail

My `Outlook 2021` (Outlook 16 0 17029 20108) under *Windows 10 22H2* has developed synchronization problems.

Several times a day, it can't finish account synchronization. Sysinternals Process Explorer then shows that *Outlook* is busy in thread

```
aitrx.dll!ArtificialIntelligence_OutputView_GetFeatures_+0x32500
```

It did not help to kill this thread or to kill the related sub-process `ai.exe`

As a short-term rescue, I stopped *Outlook* and renamed

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\vfs\ProgramFilesCommonX64\Microsoft Shared\Office16\ai.exe
```

I also repeatedly scanned and repaired my `.pst` and `.ost` files using `scanpst.exe`. My Outlook is configured with five IMAP mail accounts without using Exchange.

Is there any better way to deal with these hangups?

Comment: Unless you are archiving emails to an offline PST file scanpst will do nothing to solve the problem you described and by default your likely NOT archiving emails offline

Comment: Yes. My OST and PST files are kept local. I heard that corrupt OST/PST files might cause all sorts of trouble.

Comment: `scanpst.exe` has not effect on OST files, OST files are a cache of the email that exist on the server, it could be deleted and it would be regenerated without the loss of those emails. PST on the other hand, contains those emails, and the removal of the file would result in the loss of those emails.  However, PST files are more legacy, and only used to archive emails offline.

Comment: According to [Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/repair-outlook-data-files-pst-and-ost-25663bc3-11ec-4412-86c4-60458afc5253), `scanpst.exe` can infact repair both types, PST and OST. In my case, it detected and repaired errors in both. But this hasn't remedied the sync problems.

Comment: The fact it made repairs seems like relevant information.

Comment: “ If you're using an Exchange email account, you can delete the offline Outlook Data File (.ost) and Outlook will recreate the offline Outlook Data File (.ost) the next time you open Outlook.” - Are you using an Exchange email?

Comment: Based on your description, it seems that you have introduced AI features in Outlook. However, this feature can cause performance issues or conflicts with some email accounts. Try disabling this feature first and then check if there is any problem with your account syncing.

Comment: @Soki: I would love to stop any AI features in my Outlook. But there [seems to be no easy way](https://forum.level1techs.com/t/outlook-ai-exe-how-not-to/204335) to do so.

Comment: Yes, there are some complications in following this step. You can also follow this article to troubleshoot synchronization issues from other perspectives.
https://www.howtogeek.com/887298/how-to-fix-microsoft-outlook-not-syncing/

Comment: It has been a while, how is everything going?
If you have any update about this issue, please feel free to post back.

Comment: Since I have renamed ai.exe, Outlook works responsive. I still have lengthy synchronizations with one gmail account though. Office tries to reinstall ai.exe, but this does not happen all too frequently. I notized that the repair option of Outlook for accounts now implies that account access rights are granted to Microsoft. But this is a topic for separate questions.

Comment: According to your description, it seems that AI is influencing Outlook's response.

Answer (score 0):

I’m sorry to hear that you’re experiencing synchronization problems with your Outlook 2021. Based on your description, it seems that the synchronization issue is related to the Artificial Intelligence (AI) feature of Outlook 123. The aitrx.dll module is a part of the AI feature of Outlook and is responsible for processing the AI data 1. The ai.exe process is also related to the AI feature of Outlook 23 and is used to perform most local AI functions 34.
Since you have already tried renaming the ai.exe file and repairing your .pst and .ost files using scanpst.exe,

I would suggest you try the following steps:

1. Disable the AI feature of Outlook and check if the synchronization issue persists. To disable the AI feature, follow these steps:
   o   Open Outlook.
   o   Click on the File tab.
   o   Click on Options.
   o   Click on General.
   o   Under User Interface options, uncheck the Use Intelligent Services option.
   o   Click on OK to save the changes.
   o   Restart Outlook and check if the synchronization issue persists.
2. If disabling the AI feature doesn’t help, try repairing your Office installation using the Quick Repair option. To do this, follow these steps:
   o   Close all Office applications.
   o   Open the Control Panel.
   o   Click on Programs and Features.
   o   Select Microsoft Office 2021 from the list of installed programs.
   o   Click on Change.
   o   Select the Quick Repair option.
   o   Click on Repair.
   o   Once the repair process is complete, restart your computer and check if the synchronization issue persists.

I hope these steps help you resolve the synchronization issue.

Comment: Soft removal of AI features was one of the first things I tried. But I had to remove ai.exe to get rid of AI in my Outlook. As commented on January 19th, the Office repair also did not help but unwillingly handed over my mail credentials to Microsoft. I was lucky that I still had my product key, because the repair invalidated the registration.